# how to copy a column values from specific rows to another excel file in python?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, file

I want to read rows of a excel file and if in a row have specific value, then copy column c of them to another excel file

example: in 1000 rows of first file there are 100 rows with col a value='Sara' now copy the col c of these rows to another file

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

input_file_path = 'input.xlsx'
output_file_path = 'output.xlsx'

# Mention your sheet name here 
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

# Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(input_file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Filter rows where column 'A' has the value 'a'
filtered_df = df[df['A'] == 'a']

# Create a new DataFrame with only the values from column 'C' of the filtered rows
result_df = filtered_df[['C']]

# Write the result DataFrame to a new Excel file
result_df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Have a look to this, if it is not serving your purpose please let me know.